# Changing font size and line distance in align-environment

Tags: align, fontsize, line-spacing

I would like to change the font size (and probably also the line distance) inside my formula, so that it looks roughly like this: [image]

My text currently looks like this:
[image]

I think you can clearly see the difference.

Here's what i tried:

```
\begin{align}
        k = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha\text{1}} + \frac{1}{\Large\alpha\text{1}}}
\end{align}
```

Nothing happened there.

```
{\Large
    \begin{align}
        k = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha\text{1}} + \frac{1}{\alpha\text{1}}}
\end{align}}%
```

This did actually change the font size but it also made the counter (5.5) grow and the line distance still isn't adjusted properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the font size to make the line look like in your first picture, you only need the fractions to be written in display style rather than in text style. To do that, you can either add `\displaystyle` in front of the denominator, or use `\dfrac` to produce display style fractions. In any case, you can also use `\genfrac` if you want to adjust the vertical spacing in the main fraction.

Here's an example with several options. For the last one, I defined a command `\ofrac` which is like `\frac` buth with an additional optional argument to shift the denominator downwards.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ofrac}[3][0pt]{\genfrac{}{}{}{}{#2}{\raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}}}
\begin{document}
\[
k = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha_1} + \frac{1}{\alpha_2}}, \qquad
k = \frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{\alpha_1} + \dfrac{1}{\alpha_2}}, \qquad
k = \frac{1}{\displaystyle \frac{1}{\alpha_1} + \frac{1}{\alpha_2}}, \qquad
k = \ofrac[7pt]{1}{\dfrac{1}{\alpha_1} + \dfrac{1}{\alpha_2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Already looks much better. I'm still not entirely satisfied with the distance between the upper fraction line and the numbers underneath... Any way to fix this?

Comment: @jk3007 Yes, I added another example. You can modify the length `7pt` to whatever you prefer.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for :)